# Alphanumeric mysql sort

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, alphanumeric

I know this has been discussed alot and I have read alot of the q/a to get as far as I have. I almost have it working perfect but not quite yet.  The following is an example of the results I am getting and what I am needing.

```
CMG-1
CMG-1GP
CMG-1EN
CMG-2GP
CMG-2
CMG-2EN
CMG-3 
etc...
```

The code I have to order by is

```
ORDER BY CAST( SUBSTRING( items.item_num, INSTR( items.item_num,  '-' ) +1 ) AS UNSIGNED ) ASC
```

This works for the most part but is not properly sorting anything after the number. The prefix is different letters and different lengths so it's working fine to ignore the prefix.  It's after the number that isn't sorting right.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show what you are WANTING for the results...

Comment: If you want alphanumeric sort, don't cast it to a number. That throws away the letters.

Comment: DRapp, I want it to sort it as CMG-1, CMG-1EN, CMG-1GP, etc.  EN should come before GP.

Comment: I see Barmar...hmmm...ok, well then the method I am using won't work for that then.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT item_num
FROM Table1
ORDER BY LEFT(item_num,3)
       , CAST( SUBSTRING(item_num, INSTR(item_num,  '-' ) +1 ) AS UNSIGNED)
       , item_num 
;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc66b/7/0)

Comment: when I use that method it place CMG-10 before CMG-2

Comment: I see, that wasn't in the sample.  See updated.  You might not need the first part of that.